# Script not running from crontab but running from terminal?

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have a python script `/var/www/html/dummy/a.py` under Ubuntu 14.04 server 32bit

My script updates my status on twitter every time the server is rebooted

The script in question has the right permissions for execution.

My crontab is as follows:

```
reboot / usr / bin / python /var/www/html/dummy/a.py > / dev / null
```

but ... but ... my script does not run

I see the following logs:

```
Mar 12 09:05:53 dumm cron[890]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Mar 12 09:05:53 dumm CRON[904]: (gri) CMD (python /var/www/html/dummy/bb.py >/dev/null)
```

Can someone help me to know because it does not run?

Let me know if I need to provide more information?

#### EDIT:

I managed to solve this myself - it is necessary in the script to insert the full path !

Comment: Hi - don't worry if your English is not perfect.  However, your question would benefit from some effort in formatting the code and output sections to make it easier to read (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) .  Also - if you want to mark the question as solved - add an answer, rather than trying to mark the question and title solved. [Self answers are encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help other users. Or, if you truly don't think that the question is useful to leave for anyone else, just delete it.

Comment: Guau, Thank you very much , excellent commentary , real motivator, a million thanks for the tips , I'll definitely work with StackOverflow , and if my English is horrible, but I will improve !

Comment: No problem - as with anything, your English will improve with use :)  It is certainly a lot better than my Spanish! Good Luck on Stack Overflow!

Comment: did you ever try to run crontab tasks in timely manner like for every 1 minute or at particular time in a day to execute any particular script file ?

Comment: Yes, but SOLVED !, Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED I managed to solve this myself - it is necessary in the script to insert the full path !